# Put regex hit in seperate column in R

Tags: r, regex

Is it possible to find a certain string with RegEx (grep) in R in a column on the same row, and put that hit in another (new) column? I tried the following, but to no avail.

```
d$Nomen <- grep("(?i)^<N[^;]+;\\w+>\\w+", d$Right, perl=TRUE)
summary(d$Nomen)
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Nomen", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 7373
```

So let's say that the column `Right` contains a thousand characters per row. With the command above I wish to get a single hit out (only the first one it finds) and put that hit into a new column. Every row will then have a new column that contains a hit. (Excluding those that don't get matched.)

`d$Right` contains long strings such as:

```
"<VNW(onbep,det,stan,vrij,zonder);elk> van<VZ(init);van> ons<VNW(pr,pron,obl,vol,1,mv);ons> zelf<BW();zelf> verantwoordelijk<ADJ(vrij,basis,zonder);verantwoordelijk> .<LET();.> <au id=\"55\" s=\"N00541\" tb=\"291.972\"> die<VNW(aanw,det,stan,prenom,zonder,rest);die> kwaliteit<N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan);kwaliteit> kan<WW(pv,tgw,ev);kunnen> er<VNW(aanw,adv-pron,stan,red,3,getal);er> meer<VNW(onbep,grad,stan,vrij,zonder,comp);veel> dan<VG(onder);dan> ooit<BW();ooit> zijn<WW(inf,vrij,zonder);zijn> want<VG(neven);want> zoals<VG(onder);zoals> we<VNW(pers,pron,nomin,red,1,mv);we> al<BW();al> beschreven<WW(pv,verl,mv);beschrijven> hebben<WW(pv,tgw,mv);hebben> we<VNW(pers,pron,nomin,red,1,mv);we> meer<VNW(onbep,grad,stan,vrij,zonder,comp);veel> dan<VG(onder);dan> ooit<BW();ooit> mogelijkheden<N(soort,mv,basis);mogelijkheid> om<VZ(init);om> te<VZ(init);te> kiezen<WW(inf,vrij,zonder);kiezen> hoe<BW();hoe> we<VNW(pers,pron,nomin,red,1,mv);we> ons<VNW(bez,det,stan,vol,1,mv,prenom,zonder,evon);ons> leven<", 
"<VNW(onbep,det,stan,vrij,zonder);elk> van<VZ(init);van> onze<VNW(bez,det,stan,vol,1,mv,prenom,met-e,rest);ons> kinderen<N(soort,mv,basis);kind> zei<WW(pv,verl,ev);zeggen> hij<VNW(pers,pron,nomin,vol,3,ev,masc);hij> .<LET();.> <au id=\"91\" s=\"N00729\" tb=\"222.448\"> vier<TW(hoofd,prenom,stan);vier> kamelen<N(soort,mv,basis);kameel> zullen<WW(pv,tgw,mv);zullen> er<VNW(aanw,adv-pron,stan,red,3,getal);er> door<VZ(init);door> mijn<VNW(bez,det,stan,vol,1,ev,prenom,zonder,agr);mijn> naald<N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan);naald> gaan<WW(inf,vrij,zonder);gaan> .<LET();.> <au id=\"92\" s=\"N00729\" tb=\"226.907\"> 't<VNW(pers,pron,stan,red,3,ev,onz);het> bleef<WW(pv,verl,ev);blijven> echter<BW();echter> niet<BW();niet> lang<ADJ(vrij,basis,zonder);lang> bij<VZ(init);bij> vier<TW(hoofd,vrij);vier> .<LET();.> <au id=\"93\" s=\"N00729\" tb=\"228.990\"> 't<LID(bep,stan,evon);het> nieuws<N(soort,ev,basis,onz,stan);nieuws> dat<VG(onder);dat> Robert<SPEC(deeleigen);_> Puddington<SPEC(deeleigen);_> een<LID(onbep,stan,agr);e", 
"<VNW(onbep,det,stan,prenom,met-e,evz);elk> avond<N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan);avond> kan<WW(pv,tgw,ev);kunnen> lezen<WW(inf,vrij,zonder);lezen> .<LET();.> <au id=\"61\" s=\"N00533\" tb=\"333.284\"> wat<VNW(vb,pron,stan,vol,3o,ev);wat> jouw<VNW",
```

In the two first examples, I want nothing to be found, but of course this is different for each row. So with the RegEx I need to get the first hit after the first closing tag `elk>` and before a new opening tag `<N`. This last part is important: as you can see, the examples above aren't followed by <**N** (but by <**VZ**). Note that in an earlier version of this question I considered having a default value, but ideally only elements that get a hit, contain something in the column `d$Nomen`.

For the above examples `d$Nomen` would be empty for the first two rows (because the element after `elk>` isn't followed by `<N` but by `<VZ`) and for the last example the value in `d$Nomen` would be `avond` (without the preceding space), as it follows `elk>` and it is followed by `<N`.

### UPDATE 24th of December

I thought @SvenHohenstein's answer worked, because it appeared to do so in small test cases. However, in larger files errors occur. Every time an NA occurs, the next row will have as a result the hit on the *next* line instead of its own line. Here is a command to illustrate:

```
vec <- c("s=\"N01106\" tb=\"429.081\"> ja<TSW();ja> .<LET();.> <au id=\"213\" s=\"N01106\" tb=\"429.769\"> ja<TSW();ja> .<LET();.> <au id=\"214\" s=\"N01105\" tb=\"430.193\"> ",
"ouders<N(soort,mv,basis);ouder> die<VNW(betr,pron,stan,vol,persoon,getal);die> eten<WW(pv,tgw,mv);eten> 't<VNW(pers,pron,stan,red,3,ev,onz);het> ook<BW();ook>,bon<N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan);bon> h<e8><TSW();h<e8>> dan<BW();dan> krijg<WW(pv,tgw,ev);krijgen> je<VNW(pers,pron,nomin,red,2v,ev);je> op<VZ(init);op> ",
"welke<VNW(vb,det,stan,prenom,met-e,rest);welk> dag<N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan);dag> .<LET();.> <au id=\"239\" s=\"N01113\" tb=\"421.818\"> maar<VG(neven);maar> in<VZ(init);in> ",
"Brakkestein<N(eigen,ev,basis,onz,stan);Brakkestein> is<WW(pv,tgw,ev);zijn> d'r<VNW(aanw,adv-pron,stan,red,3,getal);er> ook<BW();ook> nog<BW();nog> ")

match <- regexpr("((?i)(?<=>\\s)[^<]+(?=<[^;]+;[^>]+>\\s$))", vec, perl = TRUE)
ifelse(match == -1, NA, regmatches(vec, match))
```

Expected result (last word before the last tag):

```
[1] NA    "op"  "in" "nog"
```

Actual (false) result - arrows indicate where they hits should actually be:

```
[1] NA    "in"  "nog" "op" 
            ^|    ^|    ^|
            ||----||----||
            --------------
```

As you can see, instead of the expected result the hit of the next row is used after an NA. If more NA's occur, the sequence always move one step further down. I hope the example above is illustration enough.

Comment: How about using  `value = TRUE` in `grep()`?  The question is not very clear.  Please add some sample data and desired result

Comment: @RichardScriven Still no luck, I get the same error. (See my edit for the error.)

Comment: post the contents of `d` data frame.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Do you mean my whole table? It is huge. Or do you mean a summary of the row headers?

Comment: So you want to match `<N;>w` as a minimum ?

Comment: wouldn't something like `ifelse(grepl('\\.0', mtcars$drat, perl = TRUE), mtcars$drat, NA)` do this?

Comment: @sln My bad, should have used the plus. Minimally I'd want `<N(;a>b´. (But real hits would contain words instead of one letter.)

Comment: It appears there isn't a single match for this regex in your data.

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide a *reproducible* example, e.g., `dput(head(d$Right))`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Please consider my edit.

Comment: @BramVanroy OK, what is the expected outcome for the examples?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein I added an example and added some further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach. Non-matching strings will result in `NA`:

```
match <- gregexpr("((?i)(?<=>\\s)[^<]+(?=<[^;]+;[^>]+>\\s$))", vec, perl = TRUE)
unlist(ifelse(match == -1, NA, regmatches(vec, match)))
```

An example:

```
vec <- c("s=\"N01106\" tb=\"429.081\"> ja<TSW();ja> .<LET();.> <au id=\"213\" s=\"N01106\" tb=\"429.769\"> ja<TSW();ja> .<LET();.> <au id=\"214\" s=\"N01105\" tb=\"430.193\"> ",
"ouders<N(soort,mv,basis);ouder> die<VNW(betr,pron,stan,vol,persoon,getal);die> eten<WW(pv,tgw,mv);eten> 't<VNW(pers,pron,stan,red,3,ev,onz);het> ook<BW();ook>,bon<N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan);bon> h<e8><TSW();h<e8>> dan<BW();dan> krijg<WW(pv,tgw,ev);krijgen> je<VNW(pers,pron,nomin,red,2v,ev);je> op<VZ(init);op> ",
"welke<VNW(vb,det,stan,prenom,met-e,rest);welk> dag<N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan);dag> .<LET();.> <au id=\"239\" s=\"N01113\" tb=\"421.818\"> maar<VG(neven);maar> in<VZ(init);in> ",
"Brakkestein<N(eigen,ev,basis,onz,stan);Brakkestein> is<WW(pv,tgw,ev);zijn> d'r<VNW(aanw,adv-pron,stan,red,3,getal);er> ook<BW();ook> nog<BW();nog> ")

match <- gregexpr("((?i)(?<=>\\s)[^<]+(?=<[^;]+;[^>]+>\\s$))", vec, perl = TRUE)
unlist(ifelse(match == -1, NA, regmatches(vec, match)))
# [1] NA    "op"  "in"  "nog"
```

Comment: Though it's a good catch, this doesn't seem to be the problem. When using a RegEx that is definitely a hit, the same error occurs.

Comment: @BramVanroy See the update for a different approach.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't twist things? Should `banaan` be the first argument, and the regex the second? The correct RegEx I think is `(?i)^\\w+(<N[^;]+;\\w+>)$`, however, after executing your command (both with `banaan`as first and second argument) returns the whole `d$Right` column. i.e. `d$Right == d$Nomen`.

Comment: @BramVanroy Are you sure that your regex matches any element in your column?

Comment: Absoluty sure. Confirmed it in my text editor with a regex search.

Comment: @BramVanroy Can you add some example values of `d$Right` to your question?

Comment: Please see my edit. (Couldn't add more examples due to character limit.)

Comment: I keep getting this error `(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`. I thought it might have something to do with a column `Nomen` already existing, but that's not the case. Then I googled that error, but nothing seems applicable to my case... When I run your example, it works though.

Comment: Ah yes, this one's it. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Apparently my previous comment got deleted. As you can see in my edit in the OP, something goes wrong when NA's occur.